# React formik read input value outside <Formik/> in real time onchange

Tags: reactjs, formik

Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/5wmrp396kp

I have no idea how to read the value outside the .

I just need a very simple function to show the value in other component like the helper.js

```
class ComponentOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>CompoenntOne: I wannna read the props.values.email here</div>
        <div>CompoenntOne: I wannna read the props.values.email2 here</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Any way to made this work in simple?

Answer (score -3):

Your code doesn't even have Formik components included.

Please, implement something like this basic example from [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

const BasicExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: 'jared' }}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
      }}
      render={props => (
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
            value={props.values.name}
            name="name"
          />
          {props.errors.name && <div id="feedback">{props.errors.name}</div>}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: thanks, please check the code at codesandbox, i place the formik at App.js, i dont know how to show the value at other component :(